# Oracle SQL How do you fill out missing months and corresponding 0

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have the problem to fill out missing months and corresponding 0

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR( tab.date, 'yyyy' ) "YEAR", 
            TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( tab.date, 'mm' ) )  "MONTH",
            SUM(CASE tab45.id WHEN '421' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "421"
    FROM  tab, 
          tab45,
          tab455
    WHERE ( tab.date IS NOT NULL ) AND
          ( tab.fk_id = tab45.pk_id ) AND
          ( tab.fk2_id = tab455.pk_id )
    GROUP BY  ( TO_CHAR( tab.date, 'yyyy' ) , 
                TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( tab.date, 'mm' ) ) )
    ORDER BY 1 asc ,2 asc
```

return sth like

```
year      month        421
---- ---------- ---------- 
2014          4          3 
2014          5          5
```

How do I get sth like

```
year      month        421
---- ---------- ----------
2014          1          0
2014          2          0
2014          3          0
2014          4          3 
2014          5          5
etc.
```

?

Comment: @Alex Poole : Hmm ... this question is markred as duplicated but is it really like the referred question ? .. Sure, I had seen the other, referred question beforehand, however it is NOT the same question, since my query has GRPOUP BY YEAR before, which makes it a different task .. at least for me.

Comment: Well, yes, I think it is; the CTE or subquery to generate the months (`all months` in that example) is the same, and you left join that generated list of months to your real table. You might want a different starting date and number of levels to generate; you could get those from `tab` if you want it to always cover all your actual data. In that one they happen to be limiting it to a single year and only showing the month.

Comment: [Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bf6d/3) showing generating all the months covered by the dates in your `tab` table. (I've just done a simple count and omitted the other tables for simplicity).

Comment: @AlexPoole : Thanks for the sql sniplet, but its performance is inacceptable on my huge database...

Comment: Is just generating the list of months slow? Maybe you're [hitting this problem](https://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/min-and-max-do-not-mix/) selecting both min and max together. Or maybe the date column on `tab` isn't indexed? You can used a fixed date range instead, perhaps.

Comment: @AlexPoole : good catch : the date column on `tab` is not indexed. Its getting even more head breaking... Btw I just read that `trunc` disables the index anyway, even it has existed.

Comment: You seem to be currently doing a full table scan of `tab` anyway. You could possibly move that into a CTE and get the date range from that instead, so you're only hitting the real table once. If you want the year/months shown to be be based on what's in the table, rather than a fixed range. That might need to be a separate question though, with your current query (or best version with the left join) and execution plans.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I have to understand what `move that into a CTE` means. Shall I place a separate question? I still don't have clear picture what is better for me : fixed range of year/months or based on whats in the table.. Btw the `WITH t AS (..` performs well, the performance deterioration came with the `Count` after it, which iterates over all records.

Comment: Your original query hits all `tab` records too; both should be doing a full table scan of `tab` if the date column isn't indexed? Can't really tell what's happening without the execution plans though.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Why not increasing performance by merging my actual query with a prefilled calendar table ? (which is my next question : how do you create a calendar table ... Google isn't that helpful)